# F# html parsing

Tags: html, parsing, f#, html-parsing

What other options currently exist for parsing html in F#? Currently have some regular expressions but would prefer something like Pythons Beautiful Soup http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/ or be able to using an api similar to jQuery from F#.

I have seen the fslex and fparsec but I'm not sure if someone else has already built some html parsing library with these or I would have to write my own.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have not tried using this (from F# or otherwise) but the [Html Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) seems to be the preferred solution for .NET.

[What is the best way to parse html in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c)

Comment: I've been using this for over a year now and really like it. I ran into one XPath bug, but otherwise it's been totally reliable.

Comment: What was the XPath bug? I've been using this library with XPath and so far it's been good. Hoping for some other options though.

Comment: @yanta, apparently "Html Agility Pack now supports Linq to Objects (via a LINQ to Xml Like interface)." Though I'm unsure how that can be leverage through F#.

Answer (score 1):

Today there is an [F# Data](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/index.html) library that has an [Html Parser](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/HtmlParser.html) and ability of [Html CSS Selectors](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/HtmlCssSelectors.html) (same as jQuery selectors). Also library has [Html Type Provider](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/HtmlProvider.html).